# how to put image to pdf using itextsharp with asp.net 3.5

Tags: itext, asp.net-3.5

i just want to add image to pdf document using itextSharp in asp.net 3.5.
here is my code:

```
//Photo
            try
            {
                if ((Byte[])dr["Image"] != null)
                {
                    Byte[] bytes1 = (Byte[])dr["Image"];
                    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytes1);
                    Chunk imageChunk = new Chunk(image, 0, 0);
                    phrase.Add(imageChunk);
                    document.Add(table);
                }
                else
                {
                    cell = ImageCell("../images/my_photo.gif", 30f, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    table.AddCell(cell);
                    document.Add(table);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                cell = ImageCell("../images/my_photo.gif", 30f, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table.AddCell(cell);
                document.Add(table);
            }
```

how ever pdf created successfully but image didn't appeared.

please help me....

Comment: How many columns does your table have? As documented, incomplete rows are omitted. Maybe you have a table with 2 columns and only one cell. In that case, the cell won't be rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya i found soln there is one statement that i omits.

```
document.add(image);
```